# fetching and displaying the backend json in an Angular/Ionic project

Tags: html, json, angular, api, ionic-framework

Iam working in an ionic project with angualar framework, where my requirement is to get the backend json data through an api call and read the JSON data in an HTML page.

Below is the code i tried

Broker api call:

```
http://example.com/broker/get-user-names
```

backend Json data:

```
 [

  {
"USER_NAME": "John",
"USER_COUNTRY": "USA"
},


 {
"USER_NAME": "Smith",
"USER_COUNTRY": "Canada"
 },


{
 "USER_NAME": "Peter",
"USER_COUNTRY": "Russia"
 }

 ]
```

In .ts page: defined an array to hold the data from the API

```
userNames = [];
```

(created a serive.ts and defined the api url there) and the function written is as follows;

```
   getUserNames() {
    this.apiService.getUserNames(this.apiService.loggedInUser.value.id)
     .then(res => {
     this.userNames= JSON.parse(res); 
  },
  err => {
    alert(err);
  }
)
 }
```

now when trying to display the content in HTML page its not showing anything

```
<p *ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>
```

this is not working. iam not understanding where iam going wrong, Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting the response correctly or is there some error in console??

Comment: It should be 

<p *ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>

instead of 

<p>*ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question, even with this <p *ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>. its not working

Comment: Can you show the console.log of userNames after Json.parse?

Comment: its not showing any thing, i even added an alert like this alert(JSON.stringify(this.userNames)); but its also not showing

Comment: What the network monitor showing? Did it return a response ?

Comment: its not showing any response also, i think there is some mistake in my code

Comment: Of course it will not work try like this.
`getUserNames() {
    this.apiService.getUserNames(this.apiService.loggedInUser.value.id)
     .then(res => {
     this.userNames= res; 
  },
  err => {
    alert(err);
  }
)
 }`

This need to be in the ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1):

If userNames is correctly filled:

It should be

```
<p *ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>
```

instead of

```
<p>*ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>
```

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question, even with this <p *ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}} </p>. its not working

Comment: there should be a space <p*ngFor. Please correct the question.

Comment: its not showing any thing, i even added an alert like this alert(JSON.stringify(this.userNames)); but its also not showing